# Database query, some trouble getting values from nullable fields

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm working with a huge Access (.mdb) database, for my bad luck I can't change any table design, just able to create queries, well...

Having this table (part of):

```
Table1

Id       Autonumber
Name     Text(50) Not Null
Prod     Text(8) Null
```

where Prod field is a date in format "ddMMyyyy", and not required.

With values like this:

```
Id   Name   Prod
------------------------
1    KX_W   06061988
2    AXR    (null)
3    ELR    03021957
```

Then I'm trying this query, to get records according to a date:

```
PARAMETERS [@basedate] Date;

SELECT
    Table1.Id,
    Table1.Name
FROM
    Table1
WHERE
    ((Table1.Prod) Is Not Null) AND
    (GetDate(Table1.Prod) >= [@basedate])
ORDER BY
    Table1.Id;
```

*`GetDate()` is a VBA module function that returns a Date value (dd/MM/yyyy) from a string argument.

When executing the query, I'm getting this message:
"This expression is typed incorrectly or it is too complex to be evaluated..."

The table is about 50K-record sized, but I'm pretty sure that's not the reason, there are other queries around this database, 10x more complex and run very quick!

I've tried with a piece of this table having no null values on Prod field and works fine, but when I try with the entire table, the message pop up; what is that I'm missing?

Comment: Do you run other queries using this `GetDate()` function, and if so, do they function properly?

Comment: @OverMind sure there is a lot of queries using it, but this is the **only one** sending null values to it, even with `((Table1.Prod) Is Not Null)` condition.

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Comment: Would it be easier to format the @basedate value as ddMMyyyy and compare it to table1.prod & "" (converting nulls to blank) and skip the call to getdate() entirely?

Answer (score 1):

As a last resort, you can try to use a nested subquery.

```
SELECT SUB.ID, SUB.Name
FROM
(SELECT t.ID, t.Name, t.Prod WHERE t.Prod Is Not Null) AS SUB
WHERE GetDate(SUB.Prod) >= [@basedate]
ORDER BY SUB.ID
```